# Is there a way to use $ in a tab trigger for html scoped sublime snippets?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

For some reason when I try to use the dollar sign for anything in my sublime text snippets in html, like if I create a sublime text snippet with the $ used as the tabtrigger and try to use it by typing $ and pressing tab, what I get is this:

```
<1></1>
```

And not the code I put into the snippet.  However, if I use the dollar sign as a tab trigger for any other scoped object it works fine.  Does anybody have any idea what conflict is causing this?